# How can I tell if an object is an Angular $q promise?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I have a pre-existing non-Angular API library in my project. It has a `.request` method which returns jQuery.Deferred promises. I created a simple Angular service which wraps the `.request` method to transform its result into an Angular $q promise instead. It looks something like this:

```javascript
var module = angular.module('example.api', []);

module.factory('api', function(
    $q,
    $window
) {
    function wrappedRequest() {
        var result = $window.API.request.apply($window.API, arguments);
        return $q.when(result);
    };

    return {
        request: wrappedRequest
    };
});
```

I would like to write a test which ensures that this service is functioning correctly. It will provide a mock `$window` with an `API` whose `request` method returns jQuery.Deferred promises. I need to ensure that the resulting objects are Angular $q promises.

---

How can I determine whether an object is an Angular $q promise?

For the example given in this question it would be sufficient to distinguish between jQuery.Deferred promises and Angular $q promises, but ideally we could identify Angular $q promises in general.

Answer (score 9):

Generally the better approach is to cast whatever object you do have into an Angular promise.

The concept of assimilating thenables is part of the Promises/A+ specification. Most promise libraries have a way to do this. It's what allows for awesome interop between promise implementations and a uniform API.

For this, $q uses `.when` :

> Wraps an object that might be a value or a (3rd party) then-able promise into a $q promise. This is useful when you are dealing with an object that might or might not be a promise, or if the promise comes from a source that can't be trusted.

It uses the concept of thenables to convert a 'non trusted' promise into a $q promise.

So all you have to do is

```
var p = $q.when(value); // p is now always a $q promise
                        // if it already was one - no harm
```

Comment: If you just want to test $q.when works in tests (and you really shouldn't if that's what you're doing) - you can always mock $q and add a method to it and then test for it.

Answer (score 4):

As a partial solution, adequate and appropriate for the given example, we can easily distinguish between jQuery.Deferred promises and Angular promises by checking for the presence of specific methods. For instance, Angular's $q promises have the method `catch` to handle errors, while jQuery.Deferred's promises have the method `fail`.

```javascript
function promiseIsAngularOrJQuery(promise) {
    if (typeof promise.fail === 'function') {
        return 'jquery';
    } else if (typeof promise.catch === 'function') {
        return 'angular';
    } else {
        throw new Error("this can't be either type of promise!");
    }
}
```

However, using this technique to distinguish between more different types of promises, or between promises and non-promises, could get very messy. Different implementations often use use many of the same method names. It could probably be made to work, but I'm not going down that road.

---

There is an alternative that should be able to reliably identify $q promises under reasonable conditions: operating on trusted objects in a non-hostile environment, with only a single version of Angular in use. However, some might see it as too "hacky" for serious use.

If you convert a function to a string using the `String()` function, the result is the source code for that function. We just need to use this to compare the `.then` method on a potential promise object to the `.then` method of a known $q promise object:

```javascript
function isAngularPromise(value) {
    if (typeof value.then !== 'function') {
        return false;
    }
    var promiseThenSrc = String($q.defer().promise.then);
    var valueThenSrc = String(value.then);
    return promiseThenSrc === valueThenSrc;
}
```

Comment: Why the string conversion?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Ah, good point. I didn't actually check whether the same instance of `then` was used for different promises. If so, that would be better. (I believe that jQuery *does* create unique closure instances of `then` for each promise, so you need to compare their string representations instead of identity.) EDIT: It looks like Angular also creates unique (bound) function instances for each promise's `then` method, so comparing identity would not work.

Answer (score 2):

My current solution is to use `instanceof`:

```
var AngularPromise = $q.resolve().constructor;

console.log($q.resolve() instanceof AngularPromise);  // true
```

This guarantees to return true iff the object is indeed an Angular Promise.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/cmzp7ovj/