# How to test if a function returns a angularJS promise object

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to test if a function returns an angularjs promise but there doesn't seem to be a good way to test for this can someone illuminate me?

Comment: What is your scenario that you need to do this kind of check?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I tell if an object is an Angular $q promise?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22546007/how-can-i-tell-if-an-object-is-an-angular-q-promise)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```js
if(angular.isFunction(yourFunction().then)){
  //yourFunction returns an angularjs promise.
}
```