# Unit testing $q promise within Angular service - Karma, Jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am trying to unit test an Angular service with Karma and Jasmine. I'm making I've seen a number of tutorials on how to unit test a service call from a controller, but I wish to unit test within the service itself.  `UsersService.findById()` makes an async call to find an ID within an ID, but I can't figure out how to write a passing test. I'm close, but I need a little help. Here is the function within UsersService

**users.service.js**

```
        Users.findById = function(id){
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            deferred.resolve(userList.find(function(user){
                return user.id == id;
            }));

            return deferred.promise;
        };
```

Here is the spec:

**users.service.spec.js**

```
describe("Users Factory", function(){
    var UsersService, $q, $rootScope, $provide, deferred, mockedDeferred;

    var userList = [
        { id: 1, name: "Richard Hendricks", email: "richard@piedpiper.com", phone: 4085550011, pokemon: { isPresent: true, name: "eevee"}, icon: { isPresent: false, name: null} },
        { id: 2, name: "Erlich Bachman", email: "erlich@aviato.com", phone: 4155552233, pokemon: { isPresent: true, name: "celebi"}, icon: { isPresent: false, name: null} },
        { id: 3, name: "Gavin Belson", email: "gavin@hooli.com", phone: 9165554455, pokemon: { isPresent: true, name: "snorlax"}, icon: { isPresent: false, name: null} }
    ];

    var singleUser = { id: 2, name: "Erlich Bachman", email: "erlich@aviato.com", phone: 4155552233, pokemon: { isPresent: true, name: "celebi"}, icon: { isPresent: false, name: null} };

    function mockQ(){
        deferred = $q.defer();
        spyOn(UsersService, "findById");
        return deferred;
    }

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module("testing_app"));
    beforeEach(angular.mock.module(function(_$provide_){
        $provide = _$provide_;
    }));

    beforeEach(inject(function(_UsersService_, _$q_, _$rootScope_){
        UsersService = _UsersService_;
        $q = _$q_;
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    }));

    describe("Users.findById()", function(){

        beforeEach(function(){
            mockedDeferred = mockQ();
        });

        it("should exist", function(){
            expect(UsersService.findById).toBeDefined();
        });

        it("should equal singleUser", function(){
            UsersService.findById(2);
            deferred.resolve(userList.find(function(user){
                return user.id == 2;
            }));
            expect(UsersService.findById).toHaveBeenCalled();
            expect(deferred.promise).toEqual(singleUser);
        });
    });
});
```

Here's what I have in my console:

[image: Erlich Bachman, this is your mom. You are not my baby]

I'm close, but how do I get the promise to equal the `singleUser` variable?

Comment: Yes, you are close. Use https://github.com/bvaughn/jasmine-promise-matchers . Otherwise you would have to place expect inside then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are testing the UsersService service. Therefore your test cases should exercise the service and verify it behave correctly. With this in mind checking if findById() as been called on the same function (the test) that call it do not provide any verification and is superfluous and unnecessary. In this particular test case a more productive check will be to verify that the method return a Promise like object (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22546007/how-can-i-tell-if-an-object-is-an-angular-q-promise) for more info on that). The other productive check will be to verify the response value (once promise has been resolved) of the method for known inputs. For the latter what you need to do is call `$rootScope.$apply();` before checking the resolved value of the promise against the expected one (see the [testing section on promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) from the angularjs docs for an example on that). Once we apply this recommendations the tests for findById() will be as follows:

```
describe("Users.findById()", function(){

    it("should exist", function(){
        expect(UsersService.findById).toBeDefined();
    });

    it("should produce a promise", function(){
        var p = UsersService.findById(2);

        expect(p instanceof $q.resolve().constructor).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it("should equal singleUser", function(){
        var p = UsersService.findById(2), resolvedValue;

        p.then(function(value) { resolvedValue = value; });

        $rootScope.$apply();

        expect(resolvedValue).toEqual(singleUser);
    });
});
```

On some cases the service under test is more complex and encapsulates other low level services. On those cases you need to spy or mock those lower level services in order to verify that the higher level service under test behaves as expected by checking it calls the lower level services.

Comment: Thank you @yeiniel. I have edited the code you supplied slightly so it matches with the solution for my problem, but as you did all the heavy lifting I'm giving you the credit. One question: could you explain the constructor bit a little with $q.resolve().constructor?

Comment: `$q.resolve().constructor` point to the constructor used to create $q promises and `$q.defer().promise` is an instance created using that constructor. Thats why i check using instance of. Is the way suggested in the SO answer i linked to check if a variable is a $q promise.